# Justification for writing Bayes' rule in the form of (H)ypothesis and (E)vidence?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I can see a straightforward derivation of Bayes' rule for events `A` and `B` using the definition of conditional probability. But, these are for *events* `A` and `B`, which, at least in the frequentist tradition, are the result of a trial with some sample space, a set of outcomes, and ultimately, events. How can we justify the leap to substituting a (H)ypothesis and (E)vidence into the relation? I could see the (E)vidence as an event, but it's harder to see the (H)ypothesis as the random outcome of a trial. Is it just taken to be empirically true?

Comment: Bayes rule can be derived in an entirely different way as an extension of logic without reference to set theory. See Chapters 1 and 2 of "Probability Theory: The Logic of Science" by E.T. Jaynes.

Comment: @mef, if you would like to expand your comment into an answer with a short derivation or example, I would be happy to accept it.